# Why does focal chord subtend obtuse angle at vertex in parabola?

Tags: conic-sections

PQ is the focal chord of parabola y^2=4ax. the tangents at P and Q meet at line y=2x+a. a>0.
If chord subtends an angle theta at vertex of the parabola. find tan theta.

I got the answer as 2√5/3 but it says -2√5/3, which means the angle is obtuse. why is it so?
as acc to the formula tan theta=|m1-m2/1+m1m2|, the ans should always be +ve

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The angle IS obtuse, just make a sketch with GeoGebra to see by yourself.

Comment: HINT. Two lines, when they meet, form two different (supplementary) angles. Your formula for the tangent of the angle between two lines gives the tangent of the acute angle.

Comment: If $\tan\theta_1$ is the negative slope and $\tan\theta_2$ is the positive slope, then what you want is $\tan(\pi-\theta_1+\theta_2)$.

Comment: Okk i got it thanks